# Set inclusion in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The quest is to check if one set fully includes another. As simplified example we can take four tables:

- `worker` (id, name),
- `worker_skills` (worker_id, skill),
- `job` (id, type)
- `job_required_skills` (job_id, skill)

I want to match the worker to the job but only if job required skills are fully match worker skills, i. e. if worker has some skills which are not required on job it's ok, but if job has at least one skill which worker doesn't then they don't match.

All I can think of includes ridiculous amount of joins and can't be used as a serious solution, so any advices are highly appreciated. Database is postgres 9.6. Thanks!

**EDIT**:
Some sample data:

```
+------+---------------+
| name | worker_skills |
+------+---------------+
| John | java          |
| John | sql           |
| John | ruby          |
| Jane | js            |
| Jane | html          |
+------+---------------+

+---------------------+-------------+
|        type         | job_skills  |  
+---------------------+-------------+
| Writing_queries     | sql         |  
| Writing_queries     | black_magic |  
| Generic_programming | java        |    
| Frontend_stuff      | js          |  
| Frontend_stuff      | html        | 
+---------------------+-------------+
```

Result:

```
+------+---------------------+
| John | Generic_programming |
+------+---------------------+
| Jane | Frontend_stuff      |
+------+---------------------+
```

John is perfectly qualified for `Generic_programming` (the only needed skill is in his skillset) but can't do `Writing_queries` as it requires some `black_magic`; Jane can do `Frontend_stuff` as she has both required skills.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select jrs.id, ws.id
from job_required_skills jrs left join
     worker_skills ws
     on jrs.skill = ws.skill
group by jrs.id, ws.id
having count(*) = count(ws.skill)
```